# Why does kubectl cp command terminates with exit code 126?

Tags: kubernetes, devops, kubectl, file-copying

I am trying to copy files from the pod to local using following command:

```
kubectl cp /namespace/pod_name:/path/in/pod /path/in/local
```

But the `command terminates with exit code 126` and copy doesn't take place.

Similarly while trying from local to pod using following command:

```
kubectl cp /path/in/local /namespace/pod_name:/path/in/pod
```

It throws the following error:

`OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: exec: "tar": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown`

Please help through this.

Answer (score 30):

`kubectl cp` is actually a very small wrapper around `kubectl exec whatever tar c | tar x`. A side effect of this is that you need a working `tar` executable in the target container, which you do not appear to have.

In general `kubectl cp` is best avoided, it's usually only good for weird debugging stuff.

Comment: Nice! So at least we can `kubectl exec whatever cat c > x` or `kubectl exec whatever base64 c | base64 --decode > x`

Answer (score 17):

An alternative way to copy a file from **local filesystem into a container**:

```
cat [local file path] | kubectl exec -i -n [namespace] [pod] -c [container] "--" sh -c "cat > [remote file path]"
```

Comment: So, the [remote file path] is suppossed to be is a directory or a complete filename?

Comment: [remote file path] must include a filename as "cat" command expects to.

Comment: If the container doesn't have `cat`, will this approach to work??

Comment: No, but why wouldn't it have `cat`?

Comment: distro-less images have neither `cat` or `sh`

Comment: If you are using distroless and have Kubernetes >=1.25, you can try `kubectl debug` which attaches a container of your choice to a pod

Answer (score 15):

`kubectl cp` requires the `tar` to be present in your container, as the help says:

> !!!Important Note!!!
> Requires that the 'tar' binary is present in your container
> image.  If 'tar' is not present, 'kubectl cp' will fail.

Make sure your container contains the `tar` binary in its `$PATH`

Comment: this was the solution for me! TYVM!

Answer (score 14):

Useful command to copy the file from pod to local

```
kubectl exec -n <namespace> <pod> -- cat <filename with path>  > <filename>
```

Comment: very nice workaround

Answer (score 1):

For me the `cat` worked like this:

`cat <file name> | kubectl exec -i <pod-id> -- sh -c "cat > <filename>"`

Example:

`cat file.json | kubectl exec -i server-77b7976cc7-x25s8 -- sh -c "cat > /tmp/file.json"`

Didn't need to specify namespace since I run the command from a specific project, and since we have one container, didn't need to specify it